# What algorithm does java.security.KeyStore use to encrypt the privateKey in KeyStore.setKeyEntry() and KeyStore.store()?

Tags: java, encryption, keystore

setKeyEntry() allows a password to protect a single private key, and store() allows a password to encrypt the entire keyStore. I'm using pkcs12 keystore type with the BC as the provider, and I can't figure out what it's using for encryption.

Am I able to specify the kind of encryption used in these methods?

Comment: https://neilmadden.blog/2017/11/17/java-keystores-the-gory-details/ gives some details

Answer (score 2):

The `KeyStore` implementation depends on the type you request, and for some types, will depend on the provider as well.

If you are talking about the "JKS" type, you can find a description of the format and algorithms used [here.](http://metastatic.org/source/JKS.html)

With a JKS key store, you cannot specify an encryption algorithm for private keys.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which [KeyStore provider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) you are using.

The JCEKS provider uses PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES password-based encryption algorithm.